# Access child's WEXITSTATUS

Tags: c, xcode, process

I am trying to access a child's exit status in xCode but I keep getting `0`.The code however works inside the Terminal. Am I missing something?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int pid, val1;
    char string[11];
    switch ((pid = fork())) {
        case -1:
            printf("An error occured.");
            break;
        case 0:
            printf("Enter max 10 characters: ");
            scanf("%10[^\n]%*c", string);
            exit((int)strlen(string));
        default:
            wait(&val1);
            printf("Child %d died. Count = %d\n", pid, WEXITSTATUS(val1));
            break;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

xCode's console results:

```
Enter max 10 characters: Hello
Child 19493 died. Count = 0
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

And inside the terminal:

```
Enter max 10 characters: Hello
Child 19504 died. Count = 5
```

Comment: This may or may not be related to your problem but 1) you can check `WEXITSTATUS` only if `WIFEXITED` returns non-zero. 2) You need to include `<sys/types.h>` and `<sys/wait.h>` for `wait(2)`.

Comment: Does it work if you hard code the exit status in the child? e.g. `exit(3)` pritns 3 in the parent?

Comment: @JeremyP No, it doesn't.

Comment: @usr What grinds my gears is the fact that once compiled (without warnings) it doesn't work in xCode but it works on Linux and MacOS Terminal...

Comment: Is return value of wait(...) equal to pid?

Comment: @dbrank0 In the Terminal yes, in xCode no. xCode's wait(...) returns ```-1```

Comment: And what do errno and/or explain_wait say?